# MinMaxScaler.fit_transform always return/transform to 0

Tags: python, scikit-learn, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

following is my code, in which `fit_transform()` is always transforming to 0. I used same validation data and code while model training, however in testing it is behaving differently.

Following is my validation data:

| Date | P1 | P2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-04 00:00:13 | 2.343674 | 0.000909 |
| 2021-01-04 01:00:00 | -1.339256 | -0.001019 |
| 2021-01-04 02:00:00 | 6.485042 | 0.001654 |
| 2021-01-04 03:00:00 | -3.047014 | -0.002561 |
| 2021-01-04 04:00:00 | 2.308437 | -0.000279 |

Testing data:

| Date | P1 | P2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021.01.04 00:00:13 | 2.343673841 | 0.0009093321465 |

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
sc = MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (0, 1))  

dataset_test = pd.read_csv("filePath.csv",index_col="Date",parse_dates=True)

test_x = np.array(dataset_test)

test_x = sc.fit_transform(test_x)

print("test_x: ", test_x)
```

Following is the Output:

```
test_x:  [[0. 0.]]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `MinMaxScaler` transforms each column not row. You have only one row, so every value in each column is the minimum and scaled to `0.0`.

Comment: We **do not** use `fit_transform` on the *test* data; only `transform`, with a scaler that has already been fitted to the training data.

Answer (score 1):

you should always use transform method for test data or for validation dataset. If you use fit_transform for test or validation data it will lead to data leakage and your model will not perform good on new dataset.

you can create a instance of min max scaler try to use fit_transform for training data and use the same instance for test data using transform method.

```
sc = MinMaxScaler()
x_train = sc.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test = sc.transform(x_test)
```

Comment: I dont have training data as I already have trained the model, and now I want to predict using that model so dont have x_train in this context, however; I tried sc.transform(x_test) instead of sc.fit_transform(x_test), but no luck yet.

Comment: If you have a trained model you can use your model  with `model.predict(test_x)`. You don't need to transform your test data separately if you set up your model correctly. If the preprocessing is not part of your pipeline and you lost your fitted transforms your model is useless.